# How to achieve "Click, Process then Displaying content in DIV without refreshing and redircting

Tags: php

First of all, I would like to thank all you guys for kindly enough to help me with my last question(displaying images). I Really appreciate all  your time and help.

Now I do come across with another sticky issue regarding to redirecting page, updating DIV.

My problem is that after adding product to cart, the page redirect to store page, which I really don't want. I tried to use the "#" symbol, but that raises another problem which is updating DIV for shopping cart.

I know I should use something like  Ajax and I've been searching solutions online for days. But, Sadly, I  got confused as I am a fresh fish of those. I have been 
stuck on this headache for days. Can anyone help me with it?

Below are the codes if you can see it clearly:

Display the images:

```
<div class="product">
        <h3>'.stripslashes($row['name']).'</h3>
        <div class="info">
            <img src="./product_images/'.$row['name'].'.jpg" width="150" border="2">
            <p>'.stripslashes($row['description']).'</p>
            Price:'.$row["price"].'<br>
            <font size ="2">In Stock: '.$row["qty"].'</font>
            <a href="addToCart.php?ID='.$row['id'].'"><img src="images/cart_navy.gif" border=0 alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see that to add the specific item, I call the  and send the ID to this it.

Code for add_To_Cart:

```
addToCart ();
echo "<SCRIPT language='Javascript'>
           //document.location=\"\admins/admin_index.php\";
       //document.location= ../index.html;
       //document.location=\"\./index.html\";
       document.location=\"\./store.php\";

       </SCRIPT>";}
       exit();
```

The add To Cart() function  is declared in another  script named shopping_Cart

And the shopping_Cart also contains a function named get_Cart() to display the cart details.

In the main page, which is store, I called get_Cart() to display the details of cart.

My code is a little bit messy? sorry for that. I don't know whether I explain my question clear or not. Basically, I want to click the add button of the product, and call add_To_cart()function to add the item, and updating the result in the Cart Div without refreshing and without redirecting to other pages.

By the way, my current code works for me. But the problem is that every time I click on the "add to cart" button, the page fresh and redirect to store.php.

Best wishes!!

Ming

By the way, I tried J query on my computer, the .load() function doesn't work.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs
/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn2").click(function(){
$("#test").load("load.php");
  });
});
</script>


<h3 id="test">Old Info</h3>
<button id="btn2" type="button">Load New Info</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Include the jQuery library in the header, then read the [jQuery's Ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Here's a very simple example. Let's say your page has a paragraph `<p class='content'></p>` which you want to update with content from a PHP script, located on your server.

Then you include the following JS code in your page:

```
$('.process').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php"
    }).done(function (response) {
        $('.content').html(response);
    });
});
```

Then include a link in your page that will trigger the event:

```
<a href="#" class="process">Process Action</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, I am a new to Ajax. Regarding to your code, what about passing the product id ?

Comment: See the `data` parameter in the documentation.